# How to use source maps with grunt-babel from grunt-contrib-concat

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-babel

I have set up some automation via grunt, using grunt-contrib-concat (v 0.5.1) in the first and grunt-babel (v 6.0.0) in second step. If I use the option to generate source maps with concat, the options "embed" and "inline" raise the following error with babel and no further output is generated:

```
Warning: build/script-es6.concat.js: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":88,"column":5,"lastColumn":null},"source":null,"original":{"line":null,"column":null},"name":null}
```

The option "link" apparently gets ignored, babel does its job and all code occurences in the console are displayed with the concatenated js file and line number.

Is there any workaround for this behaviour?